# jQuery: push checked checkboxes to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to add to array checked checkboxes, but the array comes up empty, what am I doing wrong on my script?

```js
var availability = [];
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {

  $('.availability input:checked').each(function() {
    availability.push($(this).attr('name'));
  });
  console.log(availability);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head></head>

<body>
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <colgroup>
      <col width="80" />
      <col width="64" span="2" />
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td width="88"></td>
        <td width="64">AM</td>
        <td width="64">PM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Monday</td>
        <td><input name="mondayAM" class="form-check-input availability" id="mondayAM" type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input name="mondayPM" class="form-check-input availability" id="mondayPM" type="checkbox" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Tuesday</td>
        <td><input name="tuesdayAM" class="form-check-input availability" id="tuesdayAM" type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input name="tuesdayPM" class="form-check-input availability" id="tuesdayPM" type="checkbox" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Wednesday</td>
        <td><input name="wednesdayAM" class="form-check-input availability" id="wednesdayAM" type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input name="wednesdayPM" class="form-check-input availability" id="wednesdayPM" type="checkbox" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Thursday</td>
        <td><input name="thursdayAM" class="form-check-input availability" id="thursdayAM" type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input name="thursdayPM" class="form-check-input availability" id="thursdayPM" type="checkbox" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Friday</td>
        <td><input name="fridayAM" class="form-check-input availability" id="fridayAM" type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input name="fridayPM" class="form-check-input availability" id="fridayPM" type="checkbox" /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this `input.availability:checked` would be the correct selector to get the input checkboxes with value checked. But doing it there would fill the array everytime the event occurs and won't ever reset the array from scratch making it grow forever. Maybe you should empty it at the beginning of the change event handler

Comment: Yes, as @DiegoDeVita suggested, that would be the correct selector, but then there will be a problem of duplicate values in the array.

Comment: done fixed. https://jsfiddle.net/em128o5c/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
var availability = [];
  $('input.availability:checked').each(function() {
    availability.push($(this).attr('name'));
  });
  console.log(availability);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head></head>

<body>
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <colgroup>
      <col width="80" />
      <col width="64" span="2" />
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td width="88"></td>
        <td width="64">AM</td>
        <td width="64">PM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Monday</td>
        <td><input name="mondayAM" class="form-check-input availability" id="mondayAM" type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input name="mondayPM" class="form-check-input availability" id="mondayPM" type="checkbox" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Tuesday</td>
        <td><input name="tuesdayAM" class="form-check-input availability" id="tuesdayAM" type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input name="tuesdayPM" class="form-check-input availability" id="tuesdayPM" type="checkbox" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Wednesday</td>
        <td><input name="wednesdayAM" class="form-check-input availability" id="wednesdayAM" type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input name="wednesdayPM" class="form-check-input availability" id="wednesdayPM" type="checkbox" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Thursday</td>
        <td><input name="thursdayAM" class="form-check-input availability" id="thursdayAM" type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input name="thursdayPM" class="form-check-input availability" id="thursdayPM" type="checkbox" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Friday</td>
        <td><input name="fridayAM" class="form-check-input availability" id="fridayAM" type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input name="fridayPM" class="form-check-input availability" id="fridayPM" type="checkbox" /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```